# How do I launch a new AWS Windows Server Instance in Japanese?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, language

Using Amazon AWS EC2, I'm trying to launch a new instance of Microsoft Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server 2012 Standard in Japanese.  When I login the website is in English, and I'm not sure how to change the language setting or even if that is necessary.

I read this article (http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2156) which makes reference to an instance language setting that I can't seem to find.  Perhaps the article is out of date.

The instance is to be launched in the AP region (Tokyo).

Comment: A co-worker in Japan referred me to ami-abd844aa, which is exactly what I needed.  Too bad I couldn't search for it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are referring to Windows instances, I assume you'd be using the AWS PowerShell Tools (http://aws.amazon.com/powershell/). You can get the latest AMI by using this command:

```
#  Set Region to Japan
Set-DefaultAWSRegion ap-northeast-1

# Get AMI for Window 2012 with SQL Standard
Get-EC2ImageByName WINDOWS_2012_SQL_SERVER_STANDARD_2012 | Select ImageId
```

You should see output similar to the following:

```
ImageId
-------
ami-85b0c084
```